# Single call vs multiple API call to Azure Search based on filter on multiple complex fields?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have to make API call to fetch data from Azure search. I need to search based on **3 different complex fields**. All 3 fields are the array of objects.

What is the suggested way - should I make just **a single call and put all 3 fields in the filter** or should I make **3 different API call one for each complex type**?

**3 Complex fields** are like below:

**1)**

```
 "SubscriptionIds": [
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "bb10a8bc-1a11-4448-9a05-b965478a3f13"
        },
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "bb10a8bc-1a11-4448-9a05-b965478a3f14"
        },
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "bb10a8bc-1a11-4448-9a05-b965478a3f15"
        }
      ]
```

**2)**

```
 "TPIds": [
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "1234"
        },
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "5678"
        },
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "6789"
        }
      ]
```

**3)**

```
 "TenantIds": [
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "tb10a8bc-1a11-4448-9a05-b965478a3f15"
        },
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "tb10a8bc-1a11-4448-9a05-b965478a3f16"
        },
        {
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Value": "tb10a8bc-1a11-4448-9a05-b965478a3f17"
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A single call is more efficient, 3 calls equals to 3 connections, if we multiply this by a considerable number of users, it could mean worse performance from both client and service side.

Apart from above, Azure Search throttles due to a variety of reasons includying the amount of queries per minute and their complexitiy, based on how you stated the queries will look like, it is preferable to have two less query calls in the pipeline to fetch data.

Comment: Thanks jdresc for the response. there is some addition in the question, please check below
there are some post processing after getting the result as below:

After getting the response I need to find out by which Id result document is matched with. And those 3 types of ids list can contains thousands of ids in the response. So the latency may increase here during the post processing (finding Id type of match). Now could you suggest is there a way that in the Azure search result so that I can get only the Id, which is matched rather getting whole list of 1000s of ids?

Comment: Is the "value" field what you are going to be searching on ? I don't see why thousands of results would be returned unless you are searching on something like "bb10a8bc" and there are thousands of IDs that start with that value. In which case there is nothing Azure Search can do, you can either search on the full id to only get the desired result or add some additional fields to filter on in that collection in order to reduce the number of results being returned.